# How to get Apache to serve SSL Bugzilla CGI from a subpage (NOT subdomain)?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite, bugzilla, cgi-bin

I'm trying to set up Bugzilla *with SSL* to be served by Apache from

https://www.foo.com/bugzilla

since I don't want to pay for an extra SSL cert to get a subdomain for bugzilla.

What is the best approach for this? Should I use mod_rewrite? There is normal PHP content being served on the other pages and I'm not sure how to direct just that one /bugzilla subdirectory to the Bugzilla installation directory.

Is editing the default-ssl conf file enough? Do I need to create another conf file? Right now https://www.foo.com/bugzilla gives a 404.

```
Mon Jan 16 10:10:25 [root@ /]# ll /var/www/bugzilla
total 1320
drwxr-x--- 16 root www-data   4096 Jan 15 21:15 ./
drwxrwsr-x 12 root staff      4096 Jan 15 12:41 ../
-rwxr-x---  1 root www-data   1664 Dec 28 18:49 admin.cgi*
-rwxr-x---  1 root www-data  30977 Dec 28 18:49 attachment.cgi*
-rwxr-x---  1 root www-data  47891 Dec 28 18:49 buglist.cgi*
drwxr-x--- 16 root www-data   4096 Jan 15 16:03 Bugzilla/
-rw-r-----  1 root www-data   3414 Dec 28 18:49 bugzilla.dtd
-rw-r-----  1 root www-data  28263 Dec 28 18:49 Bugzilla.pm
drwx------  5 root www-data   4096 Dec 28 18:49 .bzr/
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/bugzilla/>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't extract / move all the Bugzilla files. You are missing index.cgi and a whole set of other files.

There is nothing special you need to do. The quick start guide explicitly says installing it under a directory is supported:

```
1. Decide from which URL and directory under your webserver root you
   will be serving the Bugzilla webpages.
```

Comment: The entire directory is there, I just didn't paste all the contents of /var/www/bugzilla. When I get the 404, I'm not seeing any of those /bugzilla requests show up in the access logs. Does that mean it's not hitting the server?

Comment: I symlinked /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl, but I still get 404s.

Comment: @Tim, did you `a2enmod ssl` too?

Comment: @Bruno, yes Mon Jan 16 12:46:30 [root@ /etc/apache2/sites-available]# a2enmod ssl
Module ssl already enabled